# Laravel Model with Multi Column Primary Key

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key, laravel

So I have a simple table in my application which stores many to many relationship between users and orders. As such, this table has a 2 column primary key (userid, orderid) to store values.

In Laravel, I'd like to check if a certain user/order combo exists in the table, and if not, insert this row.

I cannot figure out how to use `Order::find()` to retrieve this row. Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like `Order::find(array('userid' => $userno, 'orderid' => $orderno))`, but this throws an error.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use where method:

`Order::where_userid($userno)->where_orderid($orderno)->count();` 
this line returns count of results. If it is zero, you can insert. Lastly, I would recommend you to read [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent).

Comment: According to the docs, I should be able to retrieve records like this: `Order::where("userid", "=", $userno)->where("orderid", "=", $orderno)->get();` ... Unfortunately, this returns nothing for me.

Comment: Sorry about the delayed reply, I forgot to visit stackoverflow for weeks :). Anyway, for your problem (probably you found the answer) I recommend you to activate profiler toolbar while developing (in config/application.php). So that you can see sql queries and find the problem easily.